# Upgrading NewRelic Nuget Package on Azure Websites causes Git Deploy to Fail

Tags: newrelic

I recently updated the NewRelic agent using this commmand:

```
Update-Package NewRelic.Azure.WebSites
```

When I redeploy my site, it fails with this error in the logs.  Any ideas?

```
  Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
  C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mysite\Temp\eca8e7b2-2483-4759-ba73-1c04312a8910.
KuduSync.NET from: 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mysite\Temp\eca8e7b2-2483-4759-ba73-1c04312a8910' to: 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mysite\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot'
Error: The process cannot access the file 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mysite\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\newrelic\NewRelic.Agent.Core.dll' because it is being used by another process.
Copying file: 'Web.config'
Copying file: 'bin\mysite.dll'
Copying file: 'bin\zh\mysite.resources.dll'
Copying file: 'newrelic\NewRelic.Agent.Core.dll'
An error has occurred during web site deployment
```

UPDATE:
 * I've tried uninstalling New Relic.  It tries to delete the dll and Fails.
 * I've tried a web deploy.   It fails in the same way.

Only thing left at this point is to simply create a new azure website and redeploy.
.

Comment: I've also tried recycling the app right before I've deployed, and that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When updating the New Relic .NET NuGet package for Azure Websites, try stopping the site, deploying and then restarting the instance.  The expected behavior is that the process stops, then the assets get overwritten during a deployment with the ones New Relic packs up in the site root (located at: C:\Home\site\wwwroot\newrelic):

https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/azure-web-sites#h2-1

Comment: This solution works, except if you are using git deploy, since that requires the site to be started.  That said, this is an effective workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem after updating the Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization package via NuGet. The problem can be solved by disconnecting and then reconnecting your git repository to the Azure portal.

- Go to the Azure portal website
- Click "Disconnect from GitHub" in the "quick glance" section
- After a short wait, "Set up deployment from source control" will appear in place of the mentioned link. Click it.
- Re-authorise with GitHub.

Similar steps apply for other repo types.